# $\sum_k kx^k$ for even $k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $k \in \{0,2,4,6,8 \dots \}$ How can one calculate $\sum_k kx^k$? I know that for $ k=1,2,3,\dots $ one can apply $\sum kx^{k-1}=\frac {1}{(1-x)^2}$, but in my case I do not see how to find a closed formula. Any suggestions?

Comment: Writing the sum as $\sum 2kx^{2k}=2\sum k(x^2)^k$ should make things more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parameterizing $k = 2n$ and setting $u = x^2$, we have

$$\sum_{k \text{ even}} k x^k = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (2n) x^{2n} = 2 \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} n u^n = 2u \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n u^{n - 1}$$

Now apply something from your post to compute this last sum.

---

As a fun additional exercise, use this to compute $\sum_{k \text{ odd}} kx^k$ as well.

Comment: oh yes that was obvious..thanks!

Comment: Things are usually only obvious once you've seen them....

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^{2k} = \dfrac{1}{1-x^2}$, then differentiate it : $\displaystyle \sum (2k) x^{2k-1} = \dfrac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}$, and so you need $\dfrac{2x^{2}}{(1-x^2)^2}$

Comment: There is a small typo in your last formula: a $+$ instead of a $-$.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thanks! Edited